# Why does the Sportsmanship badge not take into account your own 0 score answers?

Tags: discussion, sportsmanship-badge

The [Sportsmanship](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/119/sportsmanship) badge description states:

> Up voted 100 answers on questions where an answer of yours has a positive score.

Just curious, but why does it require a positive score?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The requirements for certain badges are set such that it's more difficult to "game" your way to earning them.

Imagine a scenario where someone hunts down questions that have a lot of answers, drops off a marginal reply on each one, and then proceeds to upvote all of the competing answers. This user would be only limited by the number of votes allotted to a user in a given day, and could get the badge in about 3 days or so.

So, with the stipulation that the answers be quality ones, the badge requires a positive score (upvotes - downvotes) on a given answer for it to qualify.